# How to generate a package.json file on local machine in current directory, using single line "docker run" command from node image

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to run the `npm init` command to spit out a package.json file on my local machines current working directory, by running a Node image on docker.

I have attempted to do it like so but haven't had the desired results described above.

```
docker run -d -v $pwd:~/tmp node:18-alpine3.14 "cd ~/tmp && npm init"
```

The command I'm passing above at the end gets passed to the Node application rather than the container it is held inside. I know this because the container exits with `Error: Cannot find module '/cd ~/tmp && npm init'`.

How can i execute commands for the container to receive rather than Node inside it in this example?

Comment: You need to put `sh -c` before that command (in much the same way you would if you tried to run it, with the double-quotes, at your local shell prompt).

Comment: (Consider whether it would be easier to just use Node on your host system, especially if you're still at a very early point in development.  You'll essentially have to repeat this long-winded `docker` command every time you want to do anything with your application.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm currently trying a completely containerized environment on my local machine, lets see how long before i pull all my hair out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cloud use `sh -c "some command"` as command, but I think it's cleaner, like below.

Using the workdir flag and also using your local user and group id so that you don't have to fix the permissions later on.

```
docker run --rm \
  --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
  --workdir /temp \
  --volume "$PWD:/tmp" \
  --tty
  --interactive
  node:18-alpine3.14 npm init
```

I am also using tty and interactive so that you can answer the questions from npm init. If you dont want questions, use `npm init -y`.